# Simple MySQL LIKE not working as expected

Tags: mysql

I have a database of information about images. I need to allow users to search for file names that contain a user-specified character string. It's not working the way it appears it should.

For example, the database contains 27 records for files whose names begin with the letter 'b'.

If I execute (in PHPMyAdmin) the query:

```
SELECT * FROM image WHERE img_name LIKE '%b%';
```

I get a list of records whose file names contain the letter 'b' (as expected).

But only 4 of the 27 records for files starting with 'b' show up in that list.

Any idea what I'm missing?

Comment: Make a small example that demonstrates the problem here: http://sqlfiddle.com/ or provide sample data as part of your question.

Comment: It would help to see all 27 img_names with identification of the 4 matches. Yes, just paste the list here.

Comment: Isn't there a CR/LF before the file names in these cases?

Comment: Could you at least show us which records do you get and which are left out?

Answer (score 0):

After I posted the question, another possibility occurred to me, which turned out to be the solution.

I looked further into the database definition (I did not design it), and it uses varbinary(255) for img_name. If I change the query to:

```
SELECT * FROM `image` WHERE CONVERT(img_name USING latin1) LIKE '%b%'
```

I get all of the records that I expect.

Answer (score 0):

You say that the ones that aren't showing up are ones that start with a 'b'.

This could be a case issue.

Convert the name to lower case like so

SELECT * FROM image WHERE strtolower(img_name) LIKE '%b%';

Comment: As it turns out, that was probably the case, but using LOWER (in MySQL it's LOWER, not strtolower) would not help. In MySQL, LIKE for character strings is always case-insensitive, LOWER would be unnecessary. For binary strings (which is what it turned out were being used), the comparison is case-sensitive, but LOWER has no effect. That's probably why the CONVERT ended up solving the problem.